# Minimum Radius of Convergence: Power Series?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, convergence-divergence, power-series

Determine the lower bound of the radius of convergence of each of the following equations:

$$(2+x^2)\ddot y- x\dot y + 4y = 0, \space\space x_0 = 0 $$
$$(3 - x^2)\ddot y - 3x\dot y - y = 0, \space\space x_0 = 0 $$

If these equations are in the form:

$$P(x)\ddot y + Q(x)\dot y + R(x)y = 0$$
and for Equation 1:
$$p(x) = Q(x) / P(x) = \frac{-x}{2+x^2}$$
$$q(x) = R(x) / P(x) = \frac{4}{2+x^2}$$
Equation 2:
$$p(x) = Q(x) / P(x) = \frac{-3x}{3-x^2}$$
$$q(x) = R(x) / P(x) = \frac{-1}{3-x^2}$$

Is the minimum radius of convergence as simple as determining the distance to the poles for $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ ?

So the answers would be: $\sqrt 2$ and $\sqrt 3$ respectively?

Or do I have to apply something like the ratio test for absolute convergence? i.e.
$$\left|x-x_0\right| \lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right |$$

I have solved for the power series solutions, so the above is also easy to compute

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is totally correct. While the first equation has solutions with the whole of $\Bbb R$ as domain, for the power series also the complex roots of the leading coefficient count for limiting the radius of convergence.